# Unable to load DLL '__Internal'

Tags: c#, dll, sdk

I'm working with Extreme reality SDK I don't know if you've heared of it, every time I run my c# project on this line:

```
GeneratorSingleton.Instance.Initialize(platformType, imgInfo);
```

I get this exception:

```
Unable to load DLL '__Internal': The specified module could not be found.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

here'se my code:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Xtr3D.Net;
    using Xtr3D.Net.BaseTypes;
    using Xtr3D.Net.ColorImage;
    using Xtr3D.Net.ExtremeMotion;
    using Xtr3D.Net.ExtremeMotion.Data;
    using Xtr3D.Net.ExtremeMotion.Interop.Types;
    namespace Ex_Real
    {
        static class Program
        {

```
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            // Initializing
            Xtr3D.Net.BaseTypes.PlatformType platformType = new PlatformType();
            Xtr3D.Net.ImageInfo imgInfo = new ImageInfo();
            GeneratorSingleton.Instance.Initialize(platformType, imgInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

though I followed the intructions in the PDF and copied The following DLLs from the “bin” folder of the SDK to the folder "Debug" from which the application is running:

```
 XTR3D_ImageAcquisition.dll
 Xtr3dInfra.dll
 Xtr3dLogger.dll
 Xtr3dManager.dll
 Xtr3dSkeleton.dll
 Xtr3D.Net.dll
 Xtr3D.Net.ExtremeMotion.dll
 EM_Trial.lic
```

and added the following references from the “bin” folder of the SDK:
     Xtr3D.Net.dll
     Xtr3D.Net.ExtremeMotion.dll

so what am I missing here? any help? 
thanks in advance

Comment: My crystal ball says that you downloaded the wrong version of the library.  "__Internal" is a Mono feature, it doesn't work on Windows.  If that doesn't help then contact the vendor for support.

Comment: I downloaded an SDK for windows I'm pretty sure of that

Answer (score 1):

There's a great utility named Depends that'll analyze your .exe/.dll and show you what is missing.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: yeah I tried it before, but the missing one in the exception is '__Internal', but the dependency walker gave me a list of (other) dlls but I didn't know where to get them, I seached the entire SDK folder and didn't find them.

Comment: So you know what lib _Internal is in but you don't have it anywhere on your machine?  You must be missing something the lib depends on. On their website they listed a full and a core version of the SDK.  Could it be that you're trying to use something that's not part of the core SDK?

Comment: yeah that's right, I downloaded the full version, is this the problem??
and I don't think I'm using somwthing that's not part of the SDK because I'm following the instructions in the PDF they provided along with the SDK, and calling that function was one of them :/

Comment: What's the name of the .lib you're missing?

Comment: this is the exception, I mentioned it in the question above: Unable to load DLL '__Internal': The specified module could not be found.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) 
I don't know how this might help but I did some further research today and it looks like this '__Internal' has something to do with unity3d

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I would try downloading/installing the unity3d package.